# Firebase Transfer or Copy database from one Android app to another

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created an Android app with package name 'com.theapp.app1' initially when setting up my Firebase for the first time. But later I decided to change my app name from 'com.theapp.app1 to 'com.theapp.app2'. I refactored my package name in Android Studio but got an error 'Gradle does not recognize 'com.theapp.app2' in google-services.json file.

In app1 I have created a json database which I want to copy to app2 in firebase without re-creating a new database in app2.  Plus, I want to delete app1 after copying its db content.

I tried renaming the app1 name to app2 in firebase but I figured out that it is impossible.

Is there a way to achieve this without the need to create a new json database in Firebase?

Comment: its very easy just update your google-service.json file with your new package name ,you can do that in the firebase website and just copy it to your app

Comment: you can do it manually also i think ,just open the google-service.json in your app and search for the package name and just rename it

Comment: @has19 i did that but the app1 package name was included in the new google-service.json file i downloaded for app2 on firebase. i don't want to see anything related to app1 in app2 at all.

Comment: What if i delete app1 . because i want to delete it from firebase. the database will also be deleted

Comment: well just make a new firebase project with your new package name and their is an option in realtime database where you can import or export json  , just use it to copy your database from the first project with the old package name

Comment: Thanks @has19 i never knew one can import and export JSon database on firebase. your answer solved the problem partially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think i can answer my question. @has9 suggestions helped me figure out that the Json database is not directly tied to an app on firebase. that is, when you create another app (app2) and delete app1, your database will not be deleted with app1. i hope i explained my answer clearly. anyways this solved my problem.